# Find the maximum value of the following function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$ f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + xy + \frac1x + \frac1y $

Find the extremum values of the above function.

For your reference, answer to the problem is - minima at $(3^{-1/3},3^{-1/3})$

But how? Please help!

Comment: You should probably specify that $x$ and $y$ are positive, else there is no minimum. Or are you looking for local extrema?

Comment: The maximum value is $+\infty$, for $x=0^+$ or $y=0^+$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrections thanks to André Nicolas and Sanchay Javeria!!

Given $f(x,y)$ you search for $df(x,y) = 0$, so in this case

$$2x dx + 2y dy + x dy + y dx - \frac{dx}{x^2} - \frac{dy}{y^2} = 0$$

or

$$ \left( 2x + y - \frac{1}{x^2} \right) dx + \left( 2y + x - \frac{1}{y^2} \right) dy = 0 $$

So we obtain

$$ \frac{2x^3 + x^2 y - 1}{x^2} = 0 $$

and

$$ \frac{2y^3 + x y^2 - 1}{y^2} = 0 $$

Then we find

$$ \big( 2 x^2 + x y + 2 y^2 \big) \big( x - y \big) = 0$$
 thus

$$ x=y$$,

whence

$$ 3 y - \frac{1}{y^2} = 0$$

So

$$ y^3 = \frac{1}{3} $$

Whence

$$ x = y = 3^{-1/3} $$

Comment: One you were at $2x^3-2y^3=0$, you could immediately conclude that $x=y$.

Comment: But we may include complex solutions...

That is $x^3 = y^3$ means that $x = \big( -\tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2} \textbf{i} \sqrt{3} \big)^\jmath y$, for $\jmath = 0, 1, 2$...

Comment: No complex solutions. We are finding extrema of a function defined for real $$x$ and $y$.

Comment: Then indead we can set $x=y$ directly... Thanx!

Comment: I think you made a mistake while solving the coefficient of dy = 0 in the second step.
It should be 
2x^3 + xy^2 − 1x^2=0 instead of 2x^3 + x^2y − 1x^2=0
That's where I was also stuck on.

Comment: You are correct!

I have changed it - thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate $f$ wrt $x$ and $y$ and set the partial derivatives equal to zero.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y-x^{-2}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y+x-y^{-2}$

Set these equal to zero and solve for $x$ and $y$ and you're done.

Now, it's important not to confuse **local** extrema (minima or maxima) with **global** extrema.

See this nice picture from Wikipedia to help demonstrate the difference:
[image]

A global min/max is the **absolute** min/max that a function can attain; a **local** min/max can be seen as a little bump where the gradient is zero.

This function has no global extrema. Justification: $x$ and $y$ can be as big as we like, and as $(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty), f(x,y)\to \infty$

However, this function *does* have a **local** extremum.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y-\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y+x-\frac{1}{y^2}=0$$

These two equations can be solved for x and y.